# How to initialize const / non-const static reference member?

Tags: c++

```
class Foo {
private:
    int m_i;

public:
    Foo(int i) : m_i(i) {}
};

class FooA
{
private:
    const static Foo & m_foo;
    static Foo & m_foo2;
};
```

Q1> how to initialize const static reference?

Q2> How to initialize non-const static reference?

Note:
You can make changes for class FooA in order to illustrate the methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the same way you initialize non-reference `static` members:

```
//Foo.cpp

const Foo & FooA::m_foo = fooObj1; 
Foo & FooA::m_foo2 = fooObj2;
```

where `fooObj1` and `fooObj2` are global variables of type `Foo`.

Note `fooObj1` and `fooObj2` must be initialized before `m_foo` and `m_foo2`, otherwise you might face [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) problem.

Comment: +1 for the //Foo.cpp comment (these assignments should be in a source file, not a header) and (if I could) another +1 for the remark about the static initialization order fiasco problem.

Comment: @Nawaz, do you think the following code is legal? `const Foo& FooA::m_foo = Foo(10);
Foo&       FooA::m_foo2 = Foo(10);`

Comment: @q0987: Did you try compiling that? Does it compile successfully? First line will compile, but you wouldn't be able to use `m_foo`. DONT DO THAT. Do this intead: `Foo foo1(10), foo2(20); const Foo & FooA::m-foo=foo1; Foo & FooA::m_foo2=foo2;`

Comment: @Nawaz, why I cannot use that? If I understand correctly, the m_foo extends the life of Foo(10). Is that correct? - thank you

Comment: @q0987: Yes. you're correct. I wanted to say : don't do this : `Foo& FooA::m_foo2 = Foo(10);` .. because it will not compile, as it tries to bind a temporary to non-const reference which is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

The same way as any other static data member:

```
Foo foo(5);
const Foo& FooA::m_foo(foo);
Foo& FooA::m_foo2(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

You initialize const and non-const static references the same way you would initialize any static member: by putting the initialization in the global scope.

```
const Foo& FooA::m_foo = ...whatever...
Foo& FooA::m_foo2 = ...whatever...
```